# Faster way to read and compare two binary files in C

Tags: c

I've written a program which reads two binary files to compare them and prints the offset at which the first difference is found and the first 16 bytes from the files starting at the point they start differing. I am also comparing the time taken to compare them. I am getting around 70 millisec time. Is there any faster way to it. Say less than 5ms ?

Here's the code for comparing binary files:

I have put start and end time before and after the function call

```
void compare_two_binary_files(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2)
{
char ch1, ch2;
int flag = 0;
int count = 0;
while (((ch1 = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) &&((ch2 = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF))
{
    if(ch1 != ch2)
    {
        fseek(fp1, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        fseek(fp2, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
    count++;
}

if (flag)
{
    printf("\nTwo files are not equal :  byte position at which two files differ is %d\n", count+1);
    for(int i=0; i < 16; i++){
         printf("%x ", fgetc(fp1));
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i < 16; i++){
         printf("%x ", fgetc(fp2));
    }
}
else
{
    printf("\nTwo files are Equal\n ", ftell(fp1)+1);

}
}
```

Comment: Memory mapping the files would probably be faster, just because there's less copying of data between kernel and userspace. -- Also, `ch1` and `ch2` need to be ints in your code, not chars: http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html

Comment: You can try `mmap` which allows you to treat the files like arrays. Or use `fread` and `memcmp` to read and compare chunks of the file. If you find a chunk that's different, you can scan byte-by-byte to find the first difference.

Comment: `ch1` and `ch2` would have to be of type `int` in order to successfully compare the return value of `fgetc()` to `EOF`. `EOF` is simply the value `-1`, and a binary symbol `0xff` will collide with that condition.

Comment: In any case its faster to read an entire buffer and compare with memcmp()

Comment: Or at least compare more than one byte per-iteration of your while loop similar to what the glibc `strlen` function does. The default read buffer size (see: `LPBUFSIZ` -- if I recall its new name correctly) in the latest glibc source which on Linux provides a default IO read buffer of 8192 bytes.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? In real-world use, a program to compare files would be subject to huge delays from getting the file contents from hardware. Those files might be stored on disks which are not even spinning when the program starts, so it would take a long time to activate the disks and get the data regardless of how efficient the program itself is. So, are you trying to solve a real-world problem with comparing files quickly or are you just learning and practicing how to write efficient code?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm just learning and practicing to write efficient code